# practical problem for linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I need a practical problem/application for linear transformations.Can someone help me? I really need it.

Comment: Do you mean just a regular problem about it and its solution?

Comment: Yes. This is what I wanted to say.

Comment: Yes. A real life example of a linear transformation.

Comment: Didn't you ask this same question a while ago? Also, there are some answers on this site, like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895840/practical-application-of-linear-transformation-as-taught-in-linear-algebra?rq=1).

Comment: Yes but i didn't get the answer that I wanted.

Comment: And in the link that you gaved me is a solution in witch are use eigenvalues, I want a aplication like that but one that can be used only with linear transformation.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide more details as to what you are looking for, and explain why some previous answers weren't what you were looking for, so people don't repeat the same answers.

Answer (score 1):

For example, pick an empty table and a carpenter's squad. Let's imagine the two acute tips of the squad represent some points $A$ (pencil's head) and $B$ (pencil's bottom), and the part of the $90$º angle is the point $C$. Put the squad as you want in the table, let's call it "position $X$". Now, move the squad to a different position, we'll call it "position $Y$". Now, what you've used to move the squad from $X$ to $Y$ is in fact a linear transformation. As you can see, the distance between the points and the scalar product has been kept the same.

This is probably not the best example but it's the one that first came to my mind.