# A real life example for the linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, applications

This was what I wanted to say in my previews questions. I need a real life example that can be solved only with linear transformation. I will be verry grateful if you can give me a problem and it' s solution. Bun I really need a "real life application". I cound't find what I wanted anywhere and I hope that maybe this time I was more specific.

Comment: You were given several examples in your two old questions. How often do you want to ask this question again?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3687122/practical-problem-for-linear-transformation

Comment: Suppose 3 gallons of gas cost \$7.50.  Now what's the price of 10 gallons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was in finance I would use linear transformations to map each security I might own to a set of risk-factor loadings.

Then use these factor loadings at the security level to find the risk-factors for a  portfolio of securities.

Use a variance-covariance matrix to take these factors to a find an expected variance for my portfolio.

Then do the same thing for my benchmark and find an expected tracking error to the benchmark.

Each of these is a linear transformation.